# Rails 4 OnmiAuth routing error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I followed Railscast episode 241, which works great with a Twitter login.

In episode 304, for OmniAuth Identity, I followed everything to the letter. This occurs after I filled in the details for a new user:

```
No route matches [POST] "/auth/identity/callback"
```

My routes.rb:

```
root "home#index"
get "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
get "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout
```

Is it because I'm using Rails 4?

Answer (score 2):

Your routes specify only GETs, but the request from omniauth-identity is a POST. Try adding a POST route to '/auth/:provider/callback'.